# I have a problem with "li" width. I had a similar problem with "div" with, but i solved. I want to putt 50% width in "li" and cnn't

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
  <li>test 4</li>
  <li>test 5</li>
  <li>test 6</li>
</ul>

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}

ul{
  width:100%;
}

li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;


}
```

> I want that `li` has this behavior:
>
> [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/zanomuzepo/edit?html,css,output)

But this way, i have that put `li` `with` equal `49%`.

Have some hack? With `div` under `div` i use `font-size: 0` but, with `li` not is possible put equal `0`.

Comment: Try with li: float: left;

Answer (score 1):

Try li{display: inline-block; width: 50%; float: left;}

Comment: No problem, gl in the future buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to solve the problem. Here is css for same html file:

```
 *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  ul{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
  }
```

Comment: @pandabuddy My pleasure man!! But please don't forget to accept answer if your question is solved. It will help other coder in future. Thank You!!!